# VSCode REST Client Extension - Loop Request

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

I have the requirement to send nearly the same POST request to a backend system several times - say 50 times.

Is there a way to put the below request into a loop?

```
###
#POST Gamer
POST {{hostURL}}/api/Gamer
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "username": "User-{{$randomInt 3 1000}}",
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Superman",
      "rpgClass": "Attacker",
      "weapon": {
        "name": "Flying",
        "damage": 100
      },
      "characterSkill": [
        {
          "skillId": 1
        },
        {
          "skillId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that the loop statement is currently not supported in Rest Client extension.

While there is an [issue opened in Github relevant to loop](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/906), it is still in *open* status at the moment. (as of May 2023)